# check regexp in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

all.
I have regexp and it working in test site, but didn't work in PHP.
https://regex101.com/r/jZ5gA3/3 - regex template and test.

PHP:

```
$re = "/.*?<tr>.*?<\/tr>.*?(<tr>).*?<\/tr>.*?/sgi"; 
$subst = "<tr style=\"backgroud: $color;\">"; 
$text = preg_replace( $re, $subst, $text );
```

Input data not change.
So, please explain me, why on regex101 find needle data and didn't find in PHP code.
Thanks.

Comment: Turn on error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and you will see, that PHP wants to tell you something.

Comment: You also misspelled `background`, but that could be just a typo here.

Comment: Works fine, because only matches <tr>, not <tr ...some_attr... >
https://regex101.com/r/jZ5gA3/4